# PassportJS - Custom Callback and set Session to false

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

Is it possible to use custom callback and disable session? In the documentation it shows how to disable session and custom callbacks, but how do i combine them?

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }

    req.logIn(user, function(err) {

      // I'm getting an error here
      // [Error: Failed to serialize user into session]

      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please make sure you use newest version of `passport` (which is `0.2.1` for today).

Please try passing `{ session: false }` as a second parameter of your `req.logIn()` function:

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }

    req.logIn(user, { session: false }, function (err) {

      // Should not cause any errors

      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

#### Reason:

At first glance, passing `{ session: false }` in `passport.authenticate()` seems to be reasonable because sourcecode of this method looks like:

```
Authenticator.prototype.authenticate = function(strategy, options, callback) {
  return this._framework.authenticate(this, strategy, options, callback);
};
```

So it **should** be able to honor second parameter. But if you start to drill down the function call stack, you realize that `session` attribute of `options` parameter is being disregarded completely. I mean, there is no reference to `options.session` inside

```
this._framework.authenticate(this, strategy, options, callback);
```

function.

So basically you want to pass it in `req.logIn()` function. Source code of this function is as follows:

```
req.logIn = function(user, options, done) {
  if (!this._passport) throw new Error('passport.initialize() middleware not in use');

  if (!done && typeof options === 'function') {
    done = options;
    options = {};
  }
  options = options || {};
  var property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
  var session = (options.session === undefined) ? true : options.session;

  this[property] = user;
  if (session) { // HERE! It will not try to serialize anything if you pass {session: false}
    var self = this;
    this._passport.instance.serializeUser(user, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) { self[property] = null; return done(err); }
      self._passport.session.user = obj;
      done();
    });
  } else {
    done && done();
  }
}
```

P.S. Please consider installing your `npm` dependencies using `npm install [package-name] --save` instead of creating `package.json` manually. `npm` will automatically fetch newest stable version.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the good one :) thanks @marekozw

Comment: Currently, Passport automatically extends the http.IncomingMessage prototype in https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/http/request.js, and the 'req.login'/'req.logIn' method is called automatically  by 'passport.authenticate()' according to http://passportjs.org/guide/login/

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried directly combining them ? 
Something like :

```
passport.authenticate('local', { "session": false }, function(err,user,info){
   //blablabla
});
```

From passport's source code, `authenticate` is defined as follows :

```
Authenticator.prototype.authenticate = function(strategy, options, callback) {
```

So I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use both parameters.

Comment: This is incorrect (at least for current Passport). The session parameter needs to be passed with the login method as per @marekozw answer.